# How do I fill in my pattern box using the same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to fill this box in by somehow reversing the operation I did above, I tried practically anything I could, but I keep getting the box fully filled with the X still inside, I need the X to become " " and everything else to be with the "." Inside. I will try to explain it better with examples below:

```
#This is what happens when I try reversing the operations after inputting "y":
###############
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
#.............#
###############
```

This is what happens when I input "n", works fine:

```
###############
#.           .#
# .         . #
#  .       .  #
#   .     .   #
#    .   .    #
#     . .     #
#      .      #
#     . .     #
#    .   .    #
#   .     .   #
#  .       .  #
# .         . #
#.           .#
###############
```

Desired output when "y" is inputted:

```
###############
# ........... #
#. ......... .#
#.. ....... ..#
#... ..... ...#
#.... ... ....#
#..... . .....#
#...... ......#
#..... . .....#   
#.... ... ....#
#... ..... ...#
#.. ....... ..#
#. ......... .#
# ........... #
###############
```

The function:

```
def box(box_size, filled_ft):
    for i in range(0, box_size):
        for e in range(0, box_size):
            if (i == 0 or i == box_size - 1 or e == 0 or e == box_size - 1):
                print("#", end="")                        
            elif (i == e or i == box_size - 1 - e):
                print(".", end="")  
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
        print("")
```

Testing Code:

```
 while True:
    box_size = int(input("Enter box size (> 2): "))
    if box_size >= 2:
        break
    print("try again")       
    
    
            
while True:
    filled = input("Do you want it filled?: ")
    if filled == "yes" or filled == "y"or filled == "n" or filled =="no":
        break
    print("try again")       
    
         
box1= box(box_size, filled)
print(box1)
```

Comment: Your `box` function does not even check the value of `filled_ft`, so I'm not sure how its output is changing *at all*.  Are you sure you posted the same code that produced the examples above?

Comment: First of all, you don't use `filled_ft` inside the `box` function. Secondly, you never convert the user input to `True` or `False`. Now you have two things to work on.

Comment: @0x5453 I tried Using this: elif (filled_ft == "yes" or filled_ft == "y"):
                                                      print(".", end="")

Comment: That looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. I used some aux variables to make it more readable.

```
def box(box_size, filled_ft):
    for i in range(0, box_size):
        for e in range(0, box_size):
            border = i == 0 or i == box_size - 1 or e == 0 or e == box_size - 1
            inner_cross = i == e or i == box_size - 1 - e
            if border:
                print("#", end="")                        
            elif inner_cross and not filled_ft:
                print(".", end="")
            elif not inner_cross and filled_ft:
                print(".", end="")
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
        print("")
```

And this is the tester:

```
while True:
    box_size = int(input("Enter box size (> 2): "))
    if box_size >= 2:
        break
    print("try again")

while True:
    filled = input("Do you want it filled?: ")
    if filled == "yes" or filled == "y" or filled == "n" or filled == "no":
        filled = filled == "yes" or filled == "y"
        break
    print("try again")


box1 = box(box_size, filled)
print(box1)
```

Comment: Now it just prints the filled in x when no is inputted, is there a change it testing code?

Comment: Do you mind attaching the tester code you used?

Comment: sure!----------